# Can't Load Image on Apple Watch Complications with New iOS 16 Widget

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, ios16

```
        Image("sticker5")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 47, height: 47)
            .scaledToFill()
```

sticker5 is a picture with 94px * 94px. This is the size recommended by guideline. The Error is

```
ComplicationsExtension[403:17806] [archiving] Widget archival failed due to image being too large [2] - (94, 94).
```

We don't want to use low pixel images. That would look terrible. Please Help!

Comment: You might be looking at the wrong guidelines https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/complications there is no way to circumvent those requirements. Vector images adjust quite well usually but some detail will likely have to go. 94x94 is only for one size.